# distance not showing correctly using the latitude and longitude android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a app where I am showing the nearest event (place) distance in km using the Latitude and Longitude. Users latitude and longitude is variable but events latitude and longitude are fixed.However, I am not able to get the correct distance is km. for example correct distance is 6.7 km in google map but its showing 8663.90 km. I am novice in android so unable to get the solution. any help will be great!! my codes are

```
 {  double doubleInstance = d.getDistance(Lat1, Lon1, d.getLatitude(), d.getLongitude(), "N");
            String dInstance = String.format("%.2f",doubleInstance);
            lblview1.setText(" " + String.valueOf(dInstance) + " Km");  }
```

and

```
{  public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {

    int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = Radius * c;
    double km = valueResult / 1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter = valueResult % 1000;
    int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
            + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

    return Radius * c;
}  }
```

Comment: Don't work too hard - use some built-in methods - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])

Comment: @TDG can you please help me with the codes???

Answer (score 2):

Set your Event location. And get your current location using location manager.

```
double latitude=lat;
double longitude=lng;    
float distance=0;
Location crntLocation=new Location("crntlocation");
crntLocation.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
crntLocation.setLongitude(currentLongitude);

Location eventLocation=new Location("eventlocation");
eventLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
eventLocation.setLongitude(longitude);


//float distance = crntLocation.distanceTo(eventLocation);  in meters
distance =crntLocation.distanceTo(eventLocation) / 1000; // in kms
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Location class method to get distance between two coordinates like;

```
Location.distanceBetween(obj.getLatitude(), obj.getLongitude(),
                                        mapCircle.getCenter().latitude, mapCircle.getCenter().longitude, distance);
```

Comment: have you check your coordinate value and change parameter value to match your coordinates?